# Trimming a URL in Powershell

Tags: powershell

How do I trim  http://eng.portal.cs.com  to get   [eng.portal.cs.com](http://eng.portal.cs.com) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use below code

```
PS: ([System.Uri]"http://eng.portal.cs.com").Host
```

result is: eng.portal.cs.com

Answer (score 1):

Try this below one

```
$Url = " http://eng.portal.cs.com";
$output = $Url.Split('/')[2];
```